# Некорректно работает цикл для копирования прямоугольника

Tags: python, циклы, графика

Есть код, который должен копировать прямоугольник вверх `N`-е количество раз, а потом эту пачку скопированных вверх ещё копирует вправо `N`-е количество раз. Но получается, что каждая новая пачка начинается с конца предыдущей пачки. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы все ровно копировалось в прямоугольник по `Y`.

```
listX=[2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000]
for j in listX:
    listY=[0,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000]
    for i in listY:
        y14=y14+i
        iRectangleParam = kompas6_api5_module.ksRectangleParam(kompas_object.GetParamStruct(kompas6_constants.ko_RectangleParam))
        iRectangleParam.Init()
        iRectangleParam.x = x14
        iRectangleParam.y = y14
        iRectangleParam.ang = 0
        iRectangleParam.height = x24
        iRectangleParam.width = y24
        iRectangleParam.style = style14
        obj = iDocument2D.ksRectangle(iRectangleParam)
```

Получается со сдвигом по диагонали:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Не очень понятно что вообще происходит и что вы хотите, но мне смутно кажется, что вам надо запомнить где-то содержимое `y14` и между циклами выставлять его обратно в запомненное значение. Но, повторюсь - я лично ничего не понял. И судя по отсутствию комментариев и ответов, другие тоже ничего не поняли.

Comment: И мало написать "у меня получается вот так", надо рядом привести пример, как должно получиться. И хорошо бы вы ещё сами разобрались, в какой переменной у вас получается не то и написали, что там получается сейчас и что там должно было получиться, тогда вам уже наверняка смогут помочь.

Comment: я пытался добавить вторую картинку но форум не позволяет, нужно чтобы маленькие прямоугольники вмещались в большой прямоугольник внизу, а не смещались вверх по диагонали